# Adding Command to Checkbox in listview xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm

I have a listview in Xamarin forms and I am trying to get a checkbox in each row with a command attached to it.

I have tried some things but nothing worked out yet, because I can't get the binded ID with it.

**The things that I have already tried are:**

- Adding a `CheckedChanged` parameter to the checkbox, I can only get `true` or `false`, but not the item this is about.

```xml
<CheckBox VerticalOptions="End" x:Name="Checkbox" IsChecked="{Binding IsBought, Mode=TwoWay}" WidthRequest="100" CheckedChanged="Checkbox_CheckedChanged"/>
```

- Tried with `GestureRecognizers` with `CommandParameter`, this won't even call the function attached to it. I tried this with `Tapped` and `Command`, maybe I need to do the command with Binding?

```xml
<CheckBox VerticalOptions="End" x:Name="Checkbox" IsChecked="{Binding IsBought, Mode=TwoWay}" WidthRequest="100" CheckedChanged="Checkbox_CheckedChanged">
  <CheckBox.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" CommandParameter="{Binding ArtikelID}"/>
  </CheckBox.GestureRecognizers>
</CheckBox>
```

I hope you can help me further :)
Have a nice day

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the `sender`'s `BindingContext`

```
void OnCheckBoxCheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var cb = (CheckBox)sender;
    var item = (MyModel)cb.BindingContext;
    var id = item.ArtikelID;
}
```

Comment: Instead of MyModel I had to put the class that the list uses. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have a command property in your ViewModel, and you want to bind every checkBox's command to that command in ViewModel, and pass the item as parameter.

In your case you have to specify the DataContext for that binding, as it is pointing to the item in that list.

Use RelativeSource to solve your problem.